# SMTP email not sending with Excel attachment

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, smtp

I have a winforms app that creates an Excel shipping file when you scan a product barcode and the details are pulled from a database into the file. The app then attaches the file to an email and sends using a company email address.

From the below code I am hitting the error message "Error: Object not set to an instance of an object", I think the object it refers to is workbook but I can't understand why it was working before and is now broken. The file is created and saved however the file does not get attached to the email as m_path doesn't seem to be updating with where the file saves...

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
// see the excel sheet behind the program  
app.Visible = false;

worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";

string[] dgvColumnNames = new string[dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1];
string[] columnNames = { "MFR", "Model", "SW", "IMEI" };
string[] contents = { "Title", productName.Text, "1"  };

// find the column number for IMEI header and write headings line to array
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    dgvColumnNames[i] += dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText.ToString() + ",";
}
int imeiCol = Array.FindIndex(dgvColumnNames, t => t.Split(',').Contains(imeiColName));

if (productName.Text != null)
{
    //write column names
    for (int i = 1; i < columnNames.Length + 1; i++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[1, i] = columnNames[i-1];
        //Format as bold and bordered for headings
        worksheet.Cells[1, 1].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A1:D1", Type.Missing);
        range.BorderAround(Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Type.Missing);
    }
    // write each row and column value to excel sheet  
    for (int r = 0; r < dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < columnNames.Length - 1; c++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[r + 2, c + 1] = contents[c].ToString();
        }
    }
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //add the imei number last in each row
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 4] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[imeiCol].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Object not set to an instance of an object:" + ex.Message);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Product not selected");
}

try
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "Excel (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
    sfd.FileName = setFileName("name");
    sfd.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        workbook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    }
    m_Path = sfd.FileName;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error :" + ex.Message);
}
workbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
app.Quit();
releaseObject(worksheet);
releaseObject(workbook);
releaseObject(app);
```

:

I then get the following message when the email fails to send, even though I have checked that the username and password are correct

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. Error: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect.

```
 private void sendEmail(string destMail, string subject, string body, string[] attachmentPath)
    {
        SmtpClient mailServer = new SmtpClient("smtp-legacy.office365.com", 587);
        mailServer.EnableSsl = true;
        mailServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@outlook.com", "password!");
        //mailServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        string from = "email@outlook.com";
        string to = destMail;
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to);

        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = body;
        foreach (string file in attachmentPath)
        {
            msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file));
        }

        mailServer.Send(msg);

    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The error message 'Error: Object not set to an instance of an object' is from your own code. Are you sure, that is the actual exception? Try `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` and/or add a debugging point and check `ex`s content. Also, read the 'notes' block [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl?view=net-6.0#remarks): `If the EnableSsl property is set to true, and the SMTP mail server does not advertise STARTTLS in the response to the EHLO command, then a call to the Send or SendAsync methods will throw an SmtpException.`

Comment: Yes I have just typed it into the code above so you can see where it is from... The smtp Email was working for the last 3-4 months with EnableSsl set to true, when I set it to false I get this
'Error in processing. The server response was: 5.7.3 STARTTLS is required to send mail [DB6PR07CA0006.eurprd07.prod.outlook.com]'

Comment: Probably a TLS1.2 issue. Which exact version and build numbers of Windows and .NET is this? See also https://office365itpros.com/2021/08/19/exchange-online-to-introduce-legacy-smtp-endpoint-in-2022/

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface I'm using .Net Framework 4.7.2... Do I need access to the companies Outlook admin in order to try using PowerShell to run the Set-TransportConfig cmdlet ?

Comment: Possibly, although .NET 4.7.2 should be using TLS 1.2 natively. Try running a Wireshark trace and see what it's doing. Which version and build number of Windows?

Comment: Ok will try. Windows 10 Home, Version 21H1 OS, build 19043.1889

Comment: Not sure what you want to see from Wireshark @Charlieface?

Comment: Whether it's trying with TLS 1.2 or not. Or you might see another TLS error.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Your code is correct, the solution is in the configuration of the user account that you are using, who needs to have SMTP sending enabled.

Here you will find information on how to enable: [Enable or disable authenticated client SMTP submission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission)

Another important detail is to confirm the user authentication , as it is not always the same as the email. In my case it was different too.

Comment: Thanks Anderson. I checked and authentication is enabled for the organization. What do you mean by the User authentication?

Comment: @Ellak123

Here: System.Net.NetworkCredential("authentication user", "password!")

In my case the authentication user is different from the email. For example: The sender "email@outlook.com" is associated with the user "US1234@outlook.com", the latter would be the one indicated to authenticate in the credential

Comment: Not sure why this would cause it to break after working for months but I will try using a different auth user. Thanks